# How do i adjust the speed of the BottomSheetBehaviour (Persistant Bottom Sheet) in android

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-transitions

I've used BottomSheetBehaviour in an app which is animating too fast for me. I would like it to slow it down by giving a custom delay to the transition from STATE_HIDDEN to STATE_EXPANDED.

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51789210/3789993

Comment: But it's the preferred speed!

Comment: @AbhayBohra that solved the problem